# simple python "printing own arguments"

Tags: python

I've just discovered that in my course, the lecturer doesn't want us to use the 'import' function, as it's apparently 'too advanced for the student's needs at this point.'

Messing around with what I am "allowed" to use, I've come up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
moo = raw_input ('moo ')
string = ''.join(moo) 
outp = string.split() 
for word in outp:
  print word
```

which gives me

```
$ ./pecho
moo hello       world
hello
world
```

How to I fiddle with *what I've got here* to put the "hello world" output on one line?

---

Original post:

I need to create a python file that "simply prints its own arguments, each separated by one space."
For example, the following command will give the output shown:

```
$ pecho first    and  then    another    one
first and then another one
$
```

IS THIS simply something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
moo = raw_input ('moo ')
print moo
```

?
If so, how do I make it so that it prints exactly only one space between the words in the output, regardless of how many tabs/spaces there are in the input?

Comment: One note: You shouldn't use the word `string` as a variable name, as it's a reserved keyword.  Maybe you missed the part where I explained what the comma does.  However, you shouldn't even need it.  Just `print string` but change the name of the string variable please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer to the revised question:

```
moo = raw_input ('moo ')
print ' '.join(moo.split())
```

Starting from the inside of the parens, we first take the input `moo` and split it up into pieces based on the whitespace.  That gives us an iterable list, similar to `sys.argv` in the old answer.

Then, I join that list using join, and a single space.  Then print the whole deal.

To understand this better, here is the same thing, but using more lines:

```
moo = raw_input('moo ')
temp_list = moo.split()
print ' '.join(temp_list)
```

Try printing the temp_list too, to see what it looks like.

Just add this as the last line, to see how a list is printed:

```
print temp_list
```

---

You probably want this:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print arg,
```

sys.argv is a list of the command line arguments.  The first one is the name of your script.

A [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) is an iterable type, so you can use the [for](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) loop to iterate on it.  I split the list such that I start with the second item in it.

I use a comma at the end of the print line to tell python not to print a newline.  There's a different method for doing that in python 3.

In [python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) the last line would be:

```
print(arg, end=" ")
```

To use [Dan D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d)'s example you would just do:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
```

You could still test to make sure you have at least one more arg than your script name.  It [joins](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) together the iterable list with a space in between each item.

Comment: I'd use `print ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])` rather than that loop.

Comment: Trying to keep it simple to understand.

Comment: >.< confused! where would the print ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) go? (p.s.thanks to you both!)

Comment: inside the `if` condition, replace the for loop with the `join()` statement

Comment: In Python 3, I'd take advantage of `print` being a function, and just use `print(*sys.argv[1:])`.

Comment: @jgritty YES! thank you, thank you! It's so satisfying when things just *work* like that after hours of trying, especially since it's meant to be simple-simple (and worth one point haha)